# Open modal box after first login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, modal-dialog

I want to launch a modal box when people login for the first time, I can work with a login counter but I have special redirect after first login because the people come from a confirmation url and after they are automaticly logged in.

The question is now what is the best way to launch this modal box? Set a cookie that you want to show the modal box or do redirect_to root_path(:first_login => true )?

Answer (score 1):

How about session variables in combination with something like this in your `index.html.erb` template?

```
<%= unless session[:first_login].nil? %>
  <div id="my-modal-box">...</div>
<% end>
```

Comment: Indeed also a solution, the only problem is that I don't now how to make the first_login? correctly. Ok if I use a login counter but after first login the login counter will still be 1 because he just logged in once. So if the method first_login? is : return self.login_count == 1 then it will always launch popup while he is visiting different pages during his login.

Comment: Yes, sailor. It also does the trick - but when using session variables you do not depend on what the URL says... Yeah, I know, it doesn't happen very often that something happens to the "?welcome=true" part of a URL in that case - but you never now. ;-)